# Android issue while trying to Upload audio file to server

Tags: android, audio, file-upload, audio-recording, android-mediarecorder

I am trying to upload audio file to server when recording gets finished. I have set CurrentDate and Time as audio file name as you can see that in below code.

```
 private String getFilename() {
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

        SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh-mm-ss");
        String currentDateandTime = sdfDate.format(new Date());

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + currentDateandTime + file_exts[currentFormat]);
}
```

So now file will be stored as **23-Jan-2014 12-34-55.mp4** inside the sdcard.

```
private void startRecording() {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
        recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
        recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        if (null != recorder) {
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.reset();
            recorder.release();
            recorder = null;
            doAudioFileUpload(getFilename());
        }
    }

    private void doAudioFileUpload(String path) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String existingFileName = path;

        System.out.println("Inside of doupload nd path is === " + path);

        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
        String urlString = "http://server-link/folder-name/upload_audio.php";
        try {
            // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    existingFileName));
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                    + existingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            // close streams
            Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
            inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            String str;

            while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
            }
            inStream.close();

        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
    }
```

Now i have used below line to store my recording in SD-card

```
recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
```

and below line for uploading audio file to server.

```
doAudioFileUpload(getFilename());
```

so it is using same getFilename() for both purpose. Now problem occurs here when first time `recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());` this calls it will store file name in sd-card as `23-Jan-2014 12-34-55.mp4` and after 20 Second's of recording when this line calls to upload audio to server it should upload `23-Jan-2014 12-34-15.mp4` this file but instead of this it is searching for `23-Jan-2014 12-34-55.mp4` file and giving me error of File not found.

So basically after recording starts , when i call `doAudioFileUpload(getFilename());` , it starts searching for currentDateandTime file not the file which i have recorded.

I have tried to upload file with some dynamic name and it is working fine but when i try to do the same with this date and time it is giving error.

Please help me solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

**Edit** My Logcat is below

```
01-23 14:12:54.716: I/System.out(9279): Inside of doupload nd path is === /mnt/sdcard/AudioRecorder/23-Jan-2014 02-12-54.mp4
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279): error: /mnt/sdcard/AudioRecorder/23-Jan-2014 02-12-54.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/AudioRecorder/23-Jan-2014 02-12-54.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:448)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at iqualtech.skirr.Record_AudioPG.doAudioFileUpload(Record_AudioPG.java:293)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at iqualtech.skirr.Record_AudioPG.stopRecording(Record_AudioPG.java:271)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at iqualtech.skirr.Record_AudioPG.access$0(Record_AudioPG.java:265)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at iqualtech.skirr.Record_AudioPG$4.onClick(Record_AudioPG.java:124)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:432)
01-23 14:12:54.765: E/Debug(9279):  ... 16 more
01-23 14:12:54.766: D/AndroidRuntime(9279): Shutting down VM
01-23 14:12:54.766: W/dalvikvm(9279): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e14258)
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279):     at iqualtech.skirr.Record_AudioPG.doAudioFileUpload(Record_AudioPG.java:342)
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279):     at iqualtech.skirr.Record_AudioPG.stopRecording(Record_AudioPG.java:271)
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279):     at iqualtech.skirr.Record_AudioPG.access$0(Record_AudioPG.java:265)
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279):     at iqualtech.skirr.Record_AudioPG$4.onClick(Record_AudioPG.java:124)
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
01-23 14:12:54.771: E/AndroidRuntime(9279):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do, as in the same method you are calling `getFileName()` which actually implements the name of file by adding current time and date, so the first time you call, it gives you say `01-01-2014 12-12-20.mp4` and after `20` seconds recording when you try to upload file via `doUploadFile(getFileName())` it again calls that method and returns you a **renewed** file name that will be `20` seconds later that is `01-01-2014 12-12-40.mp4` . So here is your issue of calling same method twice, just use it once and here is your final code.

```
String myFileName = "";

@Override onCreate(){
    //Your recording process
    //Your uploading process
}
private void startRecording() {
    myFileName = getFilename();
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(myFileName);
    recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
    recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void stopRecording() {
    if (null != recorder) {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
        doAudioFileUpload(myFileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is working fine but it is overwriting file means it is creating only one file again and again.

Comment: for each record you need a new name that is simple, check the edit for your answer. You just call the getFileName() on start of recording rather than onCreate() :)

Comment: I will give you 100 if i can. Seriously you have given lot's of time for this answer. Really appreciate you. Thanks once again.

Comment: That's why we are here

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to record, save to sccard then upload to server, right?

Then, why not try using `FileObserver` instead? With `FileObserver` you can listen to any file operation in the directory, get the last added file (and its metadata) and then upload it using a service.

```
 // set up a file observer to watch this directory on sd card 
 observer = new FileObserver(pathToWatch) {

     @Override
     public void onEvent(int event, String file) {
         if(event == FileObserver.CREATE && !file.endWith(".mp4")){ 
             Log.d(TAG, "File created [" + pathToWatch + file + "]");       
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), file + " was saved!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                 
             // upLoadFileToServer();
         }
     }
 };

 observer.startWatching(); //START OBSERVING
```