# Upload an Android audio file while recording

Tags: c#, android, audio, file-upload

I've seen several issues and solutions about uploading an Android audio file.
My problem is that the recording me take a long time and I would want to start uploading while the recording takes place.
The reason behind this is because at the end of a 1 hour recording, the user may just stop the app, the battery may run out, etc.
To lower that risk and have the file available asap, I'd like to have a thread that starts the upload while the user records.
Streaming is not a good options because we need the file with the same quality it has in the Android, and as I understand, streaming may affect the quality if the audio.
I saw this question that relates to mine, but is not an answer to my problem:
[Android issue while trying to Upload audio file to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303228/android-issue-while-trying-to-upload-audio-file-to-server)

Comment: I think streaming is your only option, from the requirements you've just outlined.

Comment: An alternative that was offered is to have an app that runs in the background that looks for audio files created previously and uploads them.
This is my best second option, because streaming (I assume you mean UDP) doesn't guarantee integrity.
Is it not possible to have a thread uploading the file as it is being created? Again, UDP and TCP make all the difference to me.

Comment: You can do a TCP/IP stream too, doesn't have to be UDP. You should probably make it resumable too, if you're recording/sending such long files.

Comment: Thanks. I guess both your comments point to a solution that is a good compromise:
A. Use TCP to preserve the quality of the audio file.
B. Resuming where it left: On this one, I think what I'll try to do is have a background thread that looks for audio files. When it finds it, it will upload them. After that it will delete them from the unit.
Why do I compromise with B? Because there are many things that may happen in the middle: Lost battery, user powered off the unit, no internet, etc.
If you see anything not feasible in point B I would appreciate your input.
Thanks fellows.

Comment: I think your approach sounds good now. On the main thread, you ensure that whatever is recorded is definitely saved locally, and then you have another thread (or threads) checking for audio files that need to be sent - upon which you start sending them over TCP with a custom stream class which can keep track of the number of bytes uploaded and can resume from there if required. The only issue you might have here is if you require the file to be immediately available as soon as the user finishes recording. Also, sizeable backend work to get it resumable.